# Fill a specific index in tensor with a value

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, machine-learning, variable-assignment

I'm beginner with tensorflow.
I created this tensor

```
z = tf.zeros([20,2], tf.float32)
```

and I want to change the value of index `z[2,1]` and `z[2,2]` to `1.0` instead of zeros.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you *exactly* ask is not possible for two reasons:

- `z` is a constant tensor, it can't be changed.
- There is no `z[2,2]`, only `z[2,0]` and `z[2,1]`.

But assuming you want to change `z` to a variable and fix the indices, it can be done this way:

```
z = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([20,2], tf.float32))  # a variable, not a const
assign21 = tf.assign(z[2, 0], 1.0)             # an op to update z
assign22 = tf.assign(z[2, 1], 1.0)             # an op to update z

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(z))                           # prints all zeros
  sess.run([assign21, assign22])
  print(sess.run(z))                           # prints 1.0 in the 3d row
```

Comment: This works for Tensorflow 1. When running this code in TF-2:  `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'assign'`

Answer (score 2):

A much better way to accomplish this is to use [tf.sparse_to_dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense).

```
tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]],
                   output_shape=[3, 4],
                   default_value=0,
                   sparse_values=1,
                   )
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, `tf.sparse_to_dense` is deprecated recently. Thus, use [tf.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor) and then use [tf.sparse.to_dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/to_dense) to get the same result as above

Answer (score 1):

an easy way:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

init = np.zeros((20,2), np.float32)
init[2,1] = 1.0
z = tf.variable(init)
```

or use `tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates)`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update

Answer (score 0):

A Tensorflow 2.x solution to this problem would look like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

z = tf.zeros([20,2], dtype=tf.float32)

index1 = [2, 0]
index2 = [2, 1]

result = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(z, [index1, index2], [1.0, 1.0])
tf.print(result)
```

```
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [1 1]
 ...
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```