# Tensorflow: Attempting to access indexes of a Variable via tensor value?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to mimic the following behavior of numpy in TensorFlow.

```
z = np.zeros(2 * 10 - 1, dtype=np.float32)
z[[2,10]] = 1
```

what I have

```
test = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(2 * 10 - 1, dtype=tf.float32))
test[tf.constant([2,10])].assign(1)
```

I need the variable thus cannot just use the constant zeros.

When attempting this I get an error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [19], [1,2], [1,2], [1].
```

But this doesn't make sense since the index  I am providing is of rank 1, and it gets reshaped for some reason.

#### How would I mimic the behavior above?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842141/4325492) may be what you're looking for

Comment: Not exactly ( I said earlier "top notch") but realized that this does not solve it. Because the values are updated by one index at a time.  will have to use scatter update. I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the closest to what I was looking for, but I am worried that this creates a duplicate value and if test is big, then this will be huge.

```
tf.scatter_add(test,[2,10],1)
```

Better answers are welcome.