# how to get a tensorflow tf by index?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
object_for_each_prior = tf.constant([1 for i in range(8732)])
-><tf.Tensor: shape=(8732,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)>
```

Then if I want to get the position 1148,1149

```
prior_for_each_object = tf.constant([1148,1149])
object_for_each_prior[prior_for_each_object]
```

Then I got the following error

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1148, 1149], dtype=int32)>
```

If I want to get the tensor's number by index how should I approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.gather_nd` function to index tensors.
Here's example:

```
>>> object_for_each_prior = tf.constant([1 for i in range(8732)])
>>> prior_for_each_object = tf.gather_nd(object_for_each_prior, indices=[[1148], [1149]])
>>> prior_for_each_object
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1])>
>>> prior_for_each_object.numpy()
array([1, 1])
```

refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) doc to know more about `tf.gatherr_nd`.

Comment: hello thank you , and one more question if I want to change the value after I gather_nd<br/> like tf.gather(object_for_each_prior,prior_for_each_object)  = tf.constant([i for i in range(len(prior_for_each_object))]). how should I do it?

Comment: declare the variable as `tf.Variale` and reassign values using `assign` function. eg:      `a = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3])` to reassign a[0] to 3 perform `a[0] .assign(3)`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842141/14108734)